# How to connect to Sql Anywhere 9 from C#

Tags: c#, driver, sqlanywhere

I have a project in which I need to get data a Database that is on Sql Anywhere v9, searching in Google I cant find to much information because its an old version(and I/the client cant upgrade the version of the database), in the few documents that I could find mention a .Net Driver but the links are broken. Anyone know if this Driver is the only way Or if there is another way to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install any version of SQL Anywhere Developer Edition even if it's a newer version.  They are free.  This will contain all the .NET data providers and drivers.  In my experience newer versions of the Sybase client can connect to older DB Servers.
You then have to make sure you get the connection string right to connect with C#.

Comment: Do you know the right connection string? now that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: that's not always easy to get the connection string right for your situation.  http://dcx.sap.com/1200/en/dbadmin/da-conparm.html
Usually it ends up looking like:
"uid=?????;pwd=?????;server=?????;dbn=?????;CommLinks=tcpip"

Comment: OK, thanks man, now I just need to play and find the right combination.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried creating an ODBC connection and talking to the database via ODBC?

[ODBC Tutorial](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/csharp/ado-net-odbc.html)

Comment: But still need an ODBC Driver for Sql Anywhere 9 no?

Comment: Yes. I believe it should be installed when you install the Sybase 9 engine - "Adaptive Server Anywhere 9".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using C# to connect to a version 10 server, here is the connection string I found that works for me:

`Provider=SAOLEDB;LINKS=tcpip(host=1.2.3.4,PORT=123;DoBroadcast=None);ServerName=SQLANYWHERE9;Integrated Security = True; User ID = database; PWD = password`

Answer (score 0):

I've just used iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere and System.Security.Permissions.

```
var connection = new SAConnection(ConnectionString);
```